# How can I use Lisp subseq using colon (or other non-alphanumeric characters)?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, subsequence

I need to extract a substring from a string; the substring is enclosed by ":" and ";". E.g.

`:substring;`

But with Lisp (SBCL), I'm having trouble extracting the substring. When I run:

`(subseq "8.I:123;" : ;)`

I get:

```
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1000510083}>:
  illegal terminating character after a colon: #\

    Stream: #<SYNONYM-STREAM :SYMBOL SB-SYS:*STDIN* {1000025923}>

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

(SB-IMPL::READ-TOKEN #<SYNONYM-STREAM :SYMBOL SB-SYS:*STDIN* {1000025923}> #\:)
```

I've tried preceding the colon and semicolon with \ but that throws a different error. Can anyone advise? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: additionally `(subseq "8.I:123;" : ;)` ----> neither `:` nor `;` are `character` objects. A character object is written as `#\:` . The colon is part of the symbol syntax, thus you get an error message already during reading the expression.

Comment: With the `str` library you can `split` twice: `(first (str:split ";" (second (str:split ":" "8.I:123;"))))`

Comment: TXR Lisp: `(if-match \`@nil:@val;@nil\` "8.I:123;" (list val))` → `("123")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in [docs for `subseq`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_subseq.htm), `start` and `end` are [`bounding index designators`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_b.htm#bounding_index_designator) and they can be either integer or `nil`.

`#\:` and `#\;` are characters, so you can't use them, but you can use the function [`position`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_pos_p.htm#position) to find the first index of each character and use these indices as arguments for `subseq`. You have to check that both indices exist and the second one is bigger than the first one:

```
(let* ((string "8.I:123;")
       (pos1 (position #\: string))
       (pos2 (position #\; string)))
  (when (and pos1 pos2 (> pos2 pos1))
    (subseq string
            (1+ pos1)
            pos2)))

=> "123"
```

This is a little bit cumbersome, so I suggest you to use some regex library. The following example was created with [CL-PPCRE](https://github.com/edicl/cl-ppcre/):

```
(load "~/quicklisp/setup.lisp")
(ql:quickload :cl-ppcre)

> (cl-ppcre:all-matches-as-strings "(?<=:)([^;]*)(?=;)" "8.I:123;:aa;")
("123" "aa")
```

Comment: @OliverCox See also [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). You can mark any one answer as "accepted". This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Question for you: what do the three criteria mean/refer to in your command with cl-ppcre? I can see that one describes the starting character and one the end character, but if I run "(cl-ppcre:all-matches-as-strings "(?<=:)([^;]*)" "8.I:123;:aa;")" I get the same result.

Comment: With that regex, when you run `(cl-ppcre:all-matches-as-strings "(?<=:)([^;]*)" "8.I:123;:aa")`, it returns `("123" "aa")`, but `"aa"` isn't enclosed in `:` and `;`.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a doc somewhere that breaks down the syntax?